# OCaml: Alternative ways of exposing abstract type

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I am writing a matrix module

```
module type MAT = 
sig
  type dtypes
  type 'a vec
  type mat
  val  nan : dtypes

  val make : rows:int -> cols:int -> mat
  val copy_col : mat -> int -> dtypes vec
  val write_col : dtypes vec -> mat -> int -> unit
  val row : mat -> int -> dtypes vec

end;;
```

with concrete implementation

```
module MyMat(C:CONSTRAINTS) : (MAT with type dtypes = C.dtypes) = 
struct
  type dtypes = C.dtypes
  type 'a vec = 'a array
  type mat = C.dtypes vec vec
  let nan = C.nan

  let make ~rows ~cols  = Array.make_matrix rows cols nan

  let copy_col mat int =
    let rows = Array.length mat in
    let copy = Array.make rows nan in
    let rec aux n = 
      if (n = rows) then copy else (copy.(n) <- mat.(n).(int); aux (n + 1))
    in aux 0

  let write_col vec mat int =
    let rows = Array.length mat in
    let rec aux n = 
      if (n = rows) then () else (mat.(n).(int) <- vec.(n);aux (n+1))
    in aux 0

  let row m n = m.(n)

end;;
```

In the concrete implementation, the Array module is used for `vec` and `mat`. I have three functions, `copy_col`, `write_col` and `row` which return/write slices from/to the matrix. I wanted to keep the module abstract so I did not specify the type of `'a vec` or `mat` in the signature. However, this hides the type of `'a array` so when I use those functions I cannot perform array operations such as `a.()` and so on. Is there a way to expose the abstract type for `MyMat` while still preserving it for `MAT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want the following?

```
 module MyMat(C:CONSTRAINTS) : (MAT with type dtypes = C.dtypes 
                                    and  type 'a vec = 'a array) = ...
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Currently I'm populating my matrix with types from a `CONSTRAINTS` functor. Let's say an implementation of it is `C`. `C` contains a sum type definition and unfortunately at the top-level the matrix shows the values as  `C.blah` if  `blah` was part of the sum type. Would you know how to modify the pretty-printer so it will simply display `blah`?